# Migrating away from componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

The `componentWillReceiveProps` is becoming deprecated, however, I am unclear as to how to migrate away from it. For example, a simplified version of my current looks something like this:

```
import Reorder, {reorder, reorderImmutale, reorderFromTo, reorderFromToImmutable} from 'react-reorder'

class ObjectsArea extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: this.props.objects ? this.props.objects.items : []
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    //May have to do a deep compare between nextProps.items and current items?
    if (nextProps.objects){
        this.setState({items: this.nextProps.objects.items})
    }
  }

  onReorder (event, previousIndex, nextIndex, fromId, toId) {
    let new_items = reorder(this.state.items, previousIndex, nextIndex)
    this.setState({
      items: new_items
    });
    //call to parent function
  }

  render(){
    orderable_items = <Reorder reorderId="objects" onReorder={this.onReorder.bind(this)}>
        {
            this.state.items.map(item => (
                <div key={item.id}>
                    {item.text}
                </div>
             ))
         }
    </Reorder>

    return (
         <div>{orderable_items}</div>
    )

}
```

My requirements:

1. Sometimes there will be no objects property (there isn't one on initial load)
2. When there is an objects property a sortable/draggable list is created using the `react-reorder` component
3. When items in the list are dragged to be rearranged the `onReorder` function is called.
4. The onReorder function should do two things: update the list on the screen, call a parent function passed in from props.

Currently all of this will work with componentWillReceiveProps, however, what is the proper way to migrate away from componentWillReceiveProps based on the above requirements?

Comment: But don't the items lose ordering this way when a new list arrives via props? It looks to me ordering is not this component's the responsibility

Comment: The [official docs discuss ways](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) to migrate away from `componentWillRecieveProps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Tolsee's answer is perfectly correct it is also worth mentioning that the react docs suggest **removing derived state** (state that is calculated based on props) **altogether**. There is [a great article here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) that is a great read in my opinion.

Your example fits the [Anti-pattern: Unconditionally copying props to state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state) example perfectly.

Without knowing your environment I cannot recommend a solution certainly, but to me it looks like you will be able to use the [**Fully controlled** component](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions) example.

In that case, you'd need to [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), simply use `objects.items` to render your `Reorder` child, and during the `onReorder` event simply call a function that you received as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

**In your problem you can do.**

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
  if (nextProps.objects){){
     return {items: this.nextProps.objects.items};
  }
  else return null;
}
```

Please follow [this post](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607) for better understanding